# link-to gives error, but coping the same link and opening in a new tab works perfectly

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have two routes: `/` and `/:term`

`/` Shows all the jobs.

`/:term` shows a set of filtered jobs (for).

Both the routes use the same template with renderTemplate hook.

link-to is actually generating the links properly `{{link-to 'Rails' 'term' 'rails' class="list-group-item"}}`

But on clicking, ember throws error. Whereas, when I visit the same link manually `/#/rails`, it works fine.

https://github.com/amritb/jobbs/blob/master/public/javascripts/app.js#L5

Thanks

**Stack trace:**
[image]

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error you're getting?

Comment: Sure! Added a screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you why this only happens when clicking the link, but your error says that you're not setting the `description` property properly. On line 23, change this:

```
item.description = decodeURI(item.description);
```

to this:

```
item.set('description', decodeURI(item.get('description')));
```

Ember getters and setters are kind of a pain, but they're what make Ember work. You *have* to use them when interacting with Ember objects.

Comment: Thanks. That solved the error. but there are so many issues with the app :( Anyways I need to work on those.